# Как избавиться от конструкции if else

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования, if

Есть некая переменная типа string, хранящая hostname. На основе содержания этой переменной мы должны выбирать сервис. К примеру:

```
hostname = "www.youtube.com"
service = None

if hostname == 'www.youtube.com': service = YoutubeService()
elif hostname == 'yandex.com': service YandexService()
else: raise NotSupportedError()

service.do_some_stuff()
```

Вся сложность заключается в поддержке такого кода, что если таких сервисов десятки? Каждый раз добавлять конструкцию if?

Comment: Запихивайте сопоставление в словарь.

Comment: Использовать match case из python 3.10

Comment: вы можете использовать словарь, и обращаться к нему через ссылку, таким образом можно получить сервис по ссылке

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сделайте словарь с поддерживаемыми сервисами

```
services = {
   'www.youtube.com': YoutubeService,
   'yandex.com': YandexService
}
if hostname in services:
    service = services[hostname]()
else:
    raise NotSupportedError()
```

Comment: Дабы не плодить одинаковые ответы, замечу, что так же можно сделать, что бы в месте определения сервиса он сам себя добавлял в такой словарь. И даже можно сделать декоратор класса, что бы просто объявлять его в виде `@Service('yandex.com') class YandexService: ...`

Comment: @Mike, философский вопрос :) если делать декоратор такого плана, я не очень понимаю, где кошерно хранить такой словарь? Вроде не хочется в глобальную видимость засовывать. А куда?

Comment: Можно предположить, что все такие классы-сервисы наследники одно базового класса. Словарь тогда статический член этого самого класса.

Comment: @Mike да, разумно.

Comment: @MaxU да, исправил не подумав :(